# Editing PL/SQL Developer tnsnaes.ora settings

Tags: notepad++, plsqldeveloper

I am using PL/SQL Developer 7.1.3.1381 on Windows 7
navigate to C:/blah/blah/network/admin/tnsnames.ora.
I created a shortcut of "tnsnames.ora" on the desktop, then I opened it with npp.

When I changed one line I got a popup message:
"Please check if the file is opened in another application"

How can I call <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on that file after I edit it.

I tried:

Unlocker for windows
Running npp with admin rights

I know I can Just replace it ( overwrite ), but going in that folder 30 times a day is a time rip-off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Close all opened files in Npp

2) Close all Notepad instances

Right click Notepad++ Icon

Select Properties

Click Compatibility Tab

Change Settings for all users BUTTON

On Privilege level bar

Check "Run this program as administrator"

Apply,Ok